# From 1D graph to 2D mask

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have calculated the boundaries in which I want to sample points.

For example one dataset looks like:
[image]

Now I want to find point in the red area, which I do in the following way:
The plot consist of 10 lines, so I reshape to get the region limits per value of x.

`limits = data.reshape(data.shape + (5, 2))`

Now for a particular value of `x` data looks like:

```
limits[20] = array([[  5.65624197,   6.70331962],
                    [ 13.68248989,  14.77227669],
                    [ 15.50973796,  16.61491606],
                    [ 24.03948128,  25.14907398],
                    [ 26.41541777,  27.53475798]])
```

I thought to make a mesh and mask the area as following

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
bool_array = np.zeros(Y.shape)
for j, y in enumerate(limits):
    for min_y, max_y in y:
        inds = np.where(np.logical_and(ys >= min_y, ys <= max_y))[0]
        bool_array[inds, j] = True
```

`plt.imshow(bool_array[::-1])`
(don't know why the graph need to be plotted inverted)

results in

[image]

which is indeed the data I'm looking for , now I could use the `True` values to take points with a different function.

The problem is that this code is very slow, and my datasets will get much bigger.

I would like to find a more efficient way of finding this "mask".

Comment: Just a clarification for the plot: when plotting images (`imshow`), `(0, 0)` element of the array corresponds to the `top-left` pixel. That's why the plot looks upside-down in the first place. Additionally, it would be useful if you could provide a sample data (in a file, pastebin, etc..).

Comment: Additionally, what is `i` in `np.logical_and(i >= min_y, i <= max_y)`??

Comment: how does `limits[0]` looks like?

Comment: Ah, sorry  ```i``` is ```ys```. I've edited.

Comment: ```limits[0]``` looks like: ```array([[ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan]])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several things and ended up with the following result which worked for my simple cases

```
low_bound = limits[:,:,0]
upp_bound = limits[:,:,1]

mask = np.any((low_bound[:,None,:] <= Y.T[:,:,None]) & ( Y.T[:,:,None] <= upp_bound[:,None,:]),axis=-1).T
```

I know it looks ugly. What I do is introducing an additional dimension in which I subsequently check conditions whether it lies between two ending points. At the end I collapse the additional dimension by using `np.any`.

I don't know how much faster it is compared to your code. However, given that I don't use a single `for` loop there should be a performance boost.

Check the code with your data and tell me if something goes wrong.

**Edit**:

`plt.imshow` plots `(0,0)` in the lower left edge when you use

```
plt.imshow(mask,origin='lower')
```

Comment: Works like a charm and is a factor 7 times faster! Thanks a lot.